# Unable to print after while loop in perl

Tags: perl, while-loop, printing, perl5.8, perl5.6

```
BEGIN {
   use FindBin;
   $scriptsDir = $FindBin::RealBin;
}

 sub print_log {
  ($log, $msg) = ($_[0], $_[1]);
  print $log $msg;
     }


$opt_rh_gsr = "path_to_file";
open(FO, "$opt_rh_gsr") || die "-F-: Can not open file \n";
while(<FO>) {
  if(/vdd_nets/) {
          $vdd_net = 1;
          $vdd_string = "VDD_NETS \{ \n";
               }
  if(/gnd_nets/) {
          $gnd_net = 1;
 }
     if(($gnd_net == 1)) {
     chomp();
     $new_line = $_;
     @split_new_line = split(":", $new_line);
     }
   if(($gnd_net == 1) && /\}/) {
      $gnd_net = 0;
      $gnd_string .= "\} \n";
      exit;
       }
  if($vdd_net) {
    if(/^\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+{/) {
      $paren++;
    }
    if (0 != $paren && /^\s*(\w+)\s*$/) {
     $vdd_nets{$1} = $parenvolt;
      next;
    }
    if(/^\s*}\s*$/ || /^\s+$/) {
      if (0 == $paren) {
        $vdd_net = 0; next;
      }
      else {
        $paren--;  next;
      }
    }
    chomp();
    if(/\s*\}\s*$/ && ($vdd_net == 1)){
    s/\'//g;
    $vdd_net = 0;
    @_ = split(":");
    $vdd_string .= "$_[0]  $_[1] \n";
    $vdd_string .=  "\} \n";
    next;
    }
      
  if($gnd_net) {
    if(/^\s*\}\s+$/ || /^\s+$/) {
      $gnd_net = 0;
      next;
    }
    #chomp();
    if(/\s*\}\s*$/ && ($gnd_net == 1)){
    s/\'//g;
    $gnd_net = 0;
    }
    @_ = split();
    $GNDNET = $_[0];
    if ($_[0] =~ /^\w+$/) {
      $groundnets{$_[0]} = 1;
     
    }
  }
}
}
print " done reading \n";
close(FO); 

print "closed file \n";
```

The above is not printing the last 2 print statement (before and after the close of file handle). I tried print STDOUT, that didn't work. I also tried to flush, that didn't work either.

The script is exiting after executing, so it  is not stuck in a infinite loop anywhere. I tries using perl5.6 and 5.8, but both of them have the same problem.

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I got lucky here and spotted the `exit` quickly, but even then, I can't be 100% sure that this is the error, because I don't know what your input file is. Moreover, your code is 144 lines long. Next time, try to reduce your code. For instance, you should have removed some `if`s from the loop until the issue was gone. By doing that, you probably would have noticed that removing the `if` with the `exit` was solving your problem.

Comment: That code does not look very healthy. For one thing, doesn't use `use strict; use warnings`, does not even use lexical variables. Includes a *lot* of modules but does not seem to use many of them. The `Switch` module I believe is not a recommended one. And those Perl versions are 20 years old. You should seriously consider rewriting this code.

Answer (score 3):

To exit a loop, you should use the keyword [`last`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last) instead of [`exit`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit) (which exits the whole program). This `if`:

```
if(($gnd_net == 1) && /\}/) {
    $gnd_net = 0;
    $gnd_string .= "\} \n";
    print "exiting loop $gnd_string \n";
    exit;
}
```

Should thus be:

```
if(($gnd_net == 1) && /\}/) {
    $gnd_net = 0;
    $gnd_string .= "\} \n";
    print "exiting loop $gnd_string \n";
    last;
}
```

(unless you actually wanted to exit the program, in which case the print should rather have been `print "exiting program..."`)

---

A few tips:

- Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` at the beginning of your scripts. It will catch many mistakes and save you *a lot* of time.
- Use 3-operand [`open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open) to open files (ie, `open FILEHANDLE,MODE,EXPR` instead of `open FILEHANDLE,EXPR`), and lexical filehandles (ie, `$FO` instead of `FO`). Your open should thus have been: `open my $FO, '<', $opt_rh_gsr` instead of `open(FO, "$opt_rh_gsr")`.
- Adding `|| die "-F-: Can not open file \n"` after `open` is a good idea, but 1) you should do `or die` instead of `|| die` (in this specific case it doesn't matter, but with `or` rather than `||`, you can omit the parenthesis around `open`'s arguments), and 2) you should add the name of the file you were trying to open (in that case, you'd print `die "-F-: Can not open file '$opt_rh_gsr'`). 3) add `$!` to the `die` to have the error message (`die "-F-: Can not open file '$opt_rh_gsr': $!`). And 4), as suggested by TLP, don't add a newline at the end of a `die` string.
- `sub print_log { ($log, $msg) = ($_[0], $_[1]); ...` could have been `sub print_log { ($log, $msg) = @_;`; it's a bit more idiomatic and concise.
- Indent properly your code. It's possible that indentation was lost in the copy-paste, but, if it's not the case, then you should indent better your code. This will save you a lot of time when writing/reading your code, and will save other people even more time when they'll read your code. Most IDEs have indentation features that can help you indent the code.

Comment: `...die "Cannot open '$foo' for reading: $!"` There's more to add there: 3) Don't use newline at the end of a `die` string unless you want to suppress the line number of the statement, 4) you should almost certainly always include the error `$!`. Also, you may wish to be specific about the open mode.

Comment: @TLP Right thanks, I definitely wanted to add `$!` but probably got lost in my thoughts by the end of writing this sentence.